# Cytoscape missing some edges between nodes when reading NetworkX

Tags: graph, networkx, graph-visualization, cytoscape, pyvis

I'm trying to illustrate a huge graph that I created in `NetworkX` in with `Python` using `Cytoscape` for analyzing connections. I write `NetworkX` graph into `.gml` format file and then open it with `Cytoscape`.

However, some of the nodes are missing connections!

For example, I have an edge between node `'50026'` and `'con_10_2362'`, as well as `'50026'`, `'con_10_1037'`.

[image]

But when I'm looking at the `Cytoscape` model, the nodes `'50026'` and `'con_10_2362'` are not connected! Neither on the plot nor in in data table.

[image]

When I illustrate the graph as `.htlm` file with `pyvis`, nodes are connected there correctly.

[image]

I would like to use `pyvis`, but in `Cytoscape` I can drag nodes and follow different paths and move nodes by mouse which I cannot in `.htlm`. My guess is that there is something happens during writing or reading .gml file. Has someone ever ecnountered that issue?

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the actual .gml file, it would be really hard to diagnose what might be going on.  On the other hand, if you use py4cytoscape, you can skip the .gml step entirely and write the graph directly to Cytoscape for visualization.  You could still use NetworkX to build up your graph or you could just create the nodes and edges directly.

Also, feel free to post a Cytoscape bug and attach the .gml file with information about which edges are missing.  This will allow us to do a deeper dive.